# Vlookup?? query??? Suggestions?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have the following [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q9I7XhyEGKeAk93mDyiXpP95Kc9qmiPfvnhEOcTwbIU/edit#gid=0).

```
[1]: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q9I7XhyEGKeAk93mDyiXpP95Kc9qmiPfvnhEOcTwbIU/edit#gid=0]
```

[image: Image of Google Sheet]
I could edit the fields in green (A16, B16), with A16 being a data validation drop-down list and B16 being a typed-in number.

Using `vlookup`, I can get the Base Value without any issues.

```
=VLOOKUP(A16,A2:B12,2, false)
```

What I can not figure out is how to get the factor value. For example, I have select H, which is row #9. As the size value is 1.62, which is greater than the Mid Size but less than the Max Size for that row, I want to return the Factor 2 value of 1.5.

I have tried multiple `vlookup` / `query` codes, but all don't work.

The Sum is just Base * Factor to give a final value. Ideally, I would select the lookup, enter a size and it only shows the Sum value.

Comment: Access denied on the Google Sheet - please [make it public](https://www.appypie.com/faqs/how-can-i-make-my-google-drive-document-public).

Comment: Sorry about that.  Its now public with edit rights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best way to handle this, but it does work.  Partially cause my base factor value is 1, so multipling the value by 1, does not change anything

```
=(IFNA(QUERY(A2:H12,"select D where (A = '"&A16&"' AND (C <= "&B16&" AND E > "&B16&")) ORDER BY A"),1)*IFNA(QUERY(A2:H12,"select F where (A = '"&A16&"' AND (E < "&B16&" AND G >= "&B16&")) ORDER BY A"),1)*IFNA(QUERY(A2:H12,"select H where (A = '"&A16&"' AND (G <= "&B16&")) ORDER BY A"),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This definitely is **NOT** the most efficient way, but hopefully it works:

```
=IF(A16=A2,IF(B16>B2,"1.62",C2),=IF(A16=A3,IF(B16>B3,"1.62",C3),=IF(A16=A4,IF(B16>B4,"1.62",C4),=IF(A16=A5,IF(B16>B5,"1.62",C5),=IF(A16=A6,IF(B16>B6,"1.62",C6),=IF(A16=A7,IF(B16>B7,"1.62",C7),=IF(A16=A8,IF(B16>B8,"1.62",C8),=IF(A16=A9,IF(B16>B9,"1.62",C9),=IF(A16=A10,IF(B16>B10,"1.62",C10),=IF(A16=A11,IF(B16>B11,"1.62",C11),=IF(A16=A12,IF(B16>B12,"1.62",C12),"ERROR")))))))))))
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not appear to work.  :(